# where to see xPath Extractor results in Jmeter

Tags: testing, xpath, jmeter

I am new to Jmeter, I want to see the Xpath Extractor generated results.
I have

```
 Reference Name : pt_idx
 Xpath query : //patientList/patient/idnetifierList/identifier/text()           
 Default Value : 0
```

Please clarify my doubts, can i use Xpath query generated results in Http Request?
Is those result will store in pt_idx variable?
Finally, where can i see the results?

Comment: Use Debug Sampler and View Results Tree as explained here: https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/04/10/jmeter-xpath-extractor/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can use it in an Http Request, I have previously used several [XPath Extractors](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor) and been able to use them as variables in subsequent http request using the placeholder notation `${varname}` (for you it would be `${pt_idx}`)

To verify the value of the variable, I could do it via the report by looking at the HTTP Request (as I used the variable to fill a request parameter).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

> Finally, where can i see the results?

Add a Debug sampler by going to the thread group and right clicking `Thread group -> add -> sampler -> debug sampler`. The debug sampler will give the values that the `XPath Extractor` retrieves. Simple add a `View Results Tree` and select the `debug sampler` and view the `Response data` tab and the info should be all there.